# Create component dynamically at very top of the page

Tags: angular

I would like to instantiate component at very top or body element of the page.
If i add `<new-element>` component using `viewContainerRef` from `<person>` component by `viewContainerRef.createComponent` function, it places newly created element right after it's host element.

```
<app>
    <persons>
        <person>host</person>
        <new-element>child</new-element>
    </persons>
</app>
```

Is there any proper way of creating `<new-element>` right after `<app>` element from `<person>` component.

```
<app>
    <new-element>child</new-element>
    <persons>
        <person>host</person>
    </persons>
</app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible to pass a target `ViewContainerRef` into your `person` component then it should work. You may want to use `ng-container`, which leaves no element in the DOM other than a comment:

```
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) targetRef: ViewContainerRef;
}

<app>
    <ng-container #target></ng-container>
    <persons>
        <!-- Pass the target in -->
        <person [target]="targetRef">host</person>
    </persons>
</app>
```

And then in your `person` component do:

```
@Input('target') target: ViewContainerRef;

// ...

this.target.createComponent( ... )
```

**Edit:** Since you want to use a selector as a rendering target, maybe you can create the component and then move it:

```
viewContainerRef.createComponent( ... ) 

// The new component has been rendered as a sibling, so grab it and move it

document.querySelector('body').appendChild(viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement.nextSibling);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately in my solution there is no way to pass target `ViewContainerRef` in nested manner. Basically i am looking for something like this - 
`viewContainerRef.createComponent(NewElementComponent, 'body')` where `'body'` is html selected element in which i want to render my component.